# I have to click okay for message box 4 times

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure why, but when my if statement is false and my msgbox is called I have to click okay 4 times for it to go away. How do I correct this?

My code:

```
Option Explicit
Private tskCol As String
Private unitCol As String

Private Sub txtTask_Change()

End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    tskCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Column Letter for Task Names", Type:=2)
    unitCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Column Letter for Number of Units", Type:=2)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(tskCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Copy input values to sheet
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If CStr(ActiveSheet.Range(tskCol & i).Value) = CStr(Me.txtTask.Value) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(unitCol & i).Value = Me.txtQuantity.Value
        Else
        MsgBox "Task Not Found!"
        End If
    Next i
    'Clear input controls
    Me.txtTask.Value = ""
    Me.txtQuantity.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Appears that the task wasn't found four times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question, try changing this line on the `Else` statement:

```
Msgbox "Task Not Found"
```

to

```
If i = LastRow Then Msgbox "Task Not Found"
```

You might also want to put `Exit For` if the task is found. Refactoring `IF` statement:

```
If CStr(ActiveSheet.Range(tskCol & i).Value) = CStr(Me.txtTask.Value) Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(unitCol & i).Value = Me.txtQuantity.Value
    Exit For '/* no need to continue the loop, task is found */
Else
    '/* only call msgbox if all rows are processed */
    If i = LastRow Then Msgbox "Task Not Found"
End If
```

Comment: `Exit For` is the key.

Comment: @braX It would still call the `MsgBox` multiple times without the `If`, say if match was found on the 10th row, `MsgBox` will be called 9 times already.

Comment: @L42 is there anyway to have the code keep running and replace the value multiple times? right now it exits the loop after only one match is found

Comment: @MikeMann Then remove the `Exit For`. :)